# What's the ring structure on the cohomology of a Calabi-Yau threefold?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a Calabi-Yau threefold. Then we know its betti numbers are $h^0 = h^6 = 1, h^1 = h^5 = 0, h^2 = h^4 = 1, h^3 = 204$. These can be read from the Hodge diamond, for example from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_threefold).

In other words, we know the cohomology groups of $X$ are

$$H^0 = H^6 = \mathbb{Z}, H^1 = H^5 = 0, H^2 = H^4 = \mathbb{Z}, H^3 = \mathbb{Z}^{204} .$$

**What is the ring structure on the cohomology $H^*(X)$?**

For example, what's the multiplication $ab$ for $a,b \in H^3(X)$? Will the ring structure vary for different $X$? If so, what's the ring structure on $H^*(X)$ when $X$ is the [Fermat quintic threefold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quintic_threefold)?

Answer (score 3):

There are many different CY 3-folds, not each has $h^3 = 204$. On the other hand, the multiplication in $H^3$ is a map
$$
H^3 \otimes H^3 \to H^6,
$$
which is skew-symmetric (this is odd cohomology) and unimodular (Poincar\'e duality). This determines it uniquely up to isomorphism.

Comment: What's a counter-example to $h^3 = 204$?

Comment: Almost any. For instance, an intersection of a quadric and a quartic in $\mathbb{P}^5$ has $h^3 = 180$.

Comment: Oh, by a Calabi-Yau threefold, I meant a smooth quintic threefold in $\mathbb{P}^4$.

Comment: All smooth quintic threefolds in $\mathbb{P}^4$ are diffeomorphic by Ehresmann's theorem; in particular, their cohomology rings are isomorphic.

Comment: Why is the multiplication in $H^3$ determined from being skew-symmetric and unimodular? There are still large degrees of freedom in a matrix $A$ if we only know $A^t = -A$ and $\det A = \pm 1$.

Comment: @YuhangChen  quintic threefolds are just particular examples of what a general CY3 is.

Comment: @user347489 You are right. I don't why I use smooth quintic threefolds and Calabi-Yau threefolds interchangeably. I guess I didn't see many examples of CY3.

Comment: @YuhangChen: Up to isomorphism all unimodular skew-symmetric forms are the same.

Comment: @Sasha Do you mean all matrices representing unimodular skew-symmetric forms are similar?

Comment: @YuhangChen Yes, they are.

Comment: @Sasha How to prove it? It’s not obvious to me.

Comment: @Sasha Similar matrices should have the same determinant at least.

Comment: @YuhangChen: This is linear algebra. Unimodular means determinant is 1.

Comment: @Sasha Ok. That means I have some gap to fill in linear algebra. Do you have a reference on the proof?